# Does anyone here have a recognized definition of North, South, Class1, Class2 Halo orbits?

Tags: halo-orbit

Question: What makes a halo orbit North or South, Class 1 or 2

In going thru various sites and papers I've come across lots of discussion of halo orbits being Northern, Southern, Class 1, Class 2. but have not come across an explanation of what makes a specific halo one or the other.

From what I've seen it seems that when the object in L2 halo orbit has its greatest forward velocity (nearest earth) below X-Y plane (using RLP framework, viewing from L2 towards earth/sun) it is called a northern (Class 1) halo.

Answer (score 3):

In short: Yes, there is an exact definition, but it requires some knowledge of the origin of the halo family in the Circular Restricted Three Body Problem.

You can still identify a northern or southern halo with your strategy: if perilune is **below** the XY plane, it is a **northern** halo; if perilune is *above* the XY plane, it is a *southern* halo. (In this case, the XY plane is the plane of the Moon's orbit around the Earth.) This might be a little counter intuitive, so, another good way of identifying northern or southern halos is by looking at apolune. If apolune is very far in the -Z direction, is is a southern halo; the spacecraft spends most of its time below the XY plane. Both of these explanations are certainly true for halo orbits near the Moon, but it becomes a little harder to use this strategy as the halo orbits get farther away from the Moon and closer to L2.

As an example, here is a figure showing the southern L2 halos in the Earth-Moon system (I included the figure caption too for more context, this figure comes from my MS thesis). The orbits colored purple and green in this figure, which are closer to the Moon, have easily-identifiable perilunes and apolunes. But for the more-yellow orbits, it is not as straightforward to identify where perilune and apolune are.
[image: L2 Southern Halo Orbits in the Earth-Moon CRTBP]

This leads us to a more exact definition of northern vs southern. The northern and southern halo families of orbits mirror each other over the XY plane. Both families bifurcate from the Lyapunov family of orbits, and in fact they bifurcate out of the exact same Lyapunov orbit. Here comes the distinction: the northern and southern Halo families are named based on the direction in which direction the families evolve after bifurcating from the Lyapunovs. If  you follow the evolution of the family in the +Z direction from the Lyapunov orbit, you are viewing the nothern halos. If you follow the evolution of the halos in the -Z direction, you are viewing the southern halos.

To better illustrate this, [here is a link to an animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNLVNLUIusg). The animation shows the evolution of the L2 **southern** halo family as it bifurcates in the -Z direction out of the Lyapunov family. The Lyapunov orbit from which the halos bifurcate is the first red orbit around L2, and subsequent members of the halo family are plotted on a yellow-green-purple colorscale. Near the end of the animation, two halos appear highlighted in red. This is simply to denote the range of a sub-family of halos called Near Rectilinear Halo Orbits (NRHOs).

[This video](https://youtu.be/X5O77OV9_ek) from a.i. solutions may help as well. At around 48 seconds it shows both the L1 and L2 southern and northern NRHOs. [Figure 1 in this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340130891_Coverage_Analysis_of_Lunar_CommunicationNavigation_Constellations_Based_on_Halo_Orbits_and_Distant_Retrograde_Orbits) also shows both the northern and southern halo families in their entirety.

Personally I'm not familiar with the terminology of Class 1 or Class 2, but hopefully this helps.

PS: One can easily argue that the northern and southern families of halo orbits are in fact the same family, and that denoting some of them as nothern vs southern is simply a way of dividing the family into subsets.

PPS: I've made a couple of edits to the answer in an effort to make it more clear. I hope this helps. I think my original explanation didn't quite hit the mark.

Comment: That's very helpful.  So, if the outer edge of the orbit points South, it's a Southern orbit.  Great video!  I see you have several interesting videos on youtube.

Comment: @RogerWood Yep! That will probably guide you correctly. I edited much of my answer to make it a little more clear. Hopefully it's better now. And thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is the definition for Class I and Class II halo orbits:

*Class I halo orbit*: If the sense of rotation (SOR) of the body about a libration point is **clockwise** as viewed into the **negative** direction of the x-axis.

*Class II halo orbit*: If the sense of rotation (SOR) of the body about a libration point is **counter-clockwise** as viewed into the **negative** direction of the x-axis.

This is equivalent to: Class I/Class II halos have their upper turning point (North in z-direction) lying on the more negative/positive side of the x-axis.

Definition of *Northern/Southern halo orbits*:
A body on a Northern/Southern halo orbit spends more than half of its period above/below the xy-plane (in z-direction), i.e., North/South of it.

For further details see textbook [Astronautics 3rd edition](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-74373-8_11), Section 11.5.2

[image: Discrimination between Class I/II and Norther/Southern halo orbits, for a given sense of rotation = SOR]
*emphasized text*

Comment: Thank you for posting.  It would be helpful if you could add a link to some supporting documentation.